# same user role or copy the user role to be same as the other role

Tags: plugins, php, functions, customization, capabilities

how do you make the user role "contributor" to be same as the user role "seller" by using functions.php

I've tried user role editor, but it seems to be the dokan multivendor plugin has set only into user role "seller" but I wanted to make the "contributor" to be same as the seller role

Comment: How are you creating user role "seller"?

Answer (score 1):

Contributor has the following capabilities

- delete_posts
- edit_posts
- read

You can create the "Seller" role to have same capabilities as Contributor

```
add_role(
    'seller',
    __( 'Seller' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => true,
    )
);
```

Warning from codex

**NB: This setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options, field wp_user_roles), so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation**

In `functions.php`, you should use this in [after_setup_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) hook.

**EDIT**

You can also create a user role who have same permission as another this way

```
add_role(
    'specialuser',
    __('Special User'),
    get_role('seller')->capabilities
);
```

It will grant `specialuser` same capabilities as `seller`.

Comment: Hi, what about a custom user role forexample my newly added custom role is "specialuser" I wanted to make that user role to be same as the "seller" user role

Comment: @pryde1919 check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

should I copy the code from the link provided?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme

it's a twentytwelve theme, my theme is oxygen theme, how can I impliment the code? change the word twentytwelve into oxygen?

Comment: You should post this as a comment under [sakibmoon's answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/189629/54569), and not as an answer to your own question (which is it not). A comment on that answer will generate a notification to sakibmoon, and is the proper place to ask for clarification.